# Ubuntu 14.04 admin account doesn't show desktop icon, it just shows blank desktop wallpaper

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

When I try to login to my Admin account on Ubuntu 14.04 it just shows the desktop wallpaper and nothing else.Then I tried to login to my Guest account and it's working perfectly.

Thanks, Joon

Answer (score 0):

First of all **linux** works with a concept called multi-user, that means that an operating system is considered **"multi-user"** is if allows multiple people to use a computer and not affect each other's 'stuff'.

So try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to go to terminaland type:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
reboot`